# array of String^ C++/cli

Tags: arrays, winforms, c++-cli

i create a windows form project (with visual studio 2017)

and trying to create a array of String^ when i write this code:

```
array<String^>^ practic_prime = gcnew array<String^> {"TokenONE", "TokenTWO"};
```

i get a lot of errors! but according to this  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes#A5
it is should be ok...

usually in c++ i can write this code:

```
string practic_prime[] = { "Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow" };
```

but i need the String^ (it is good for unicode)

how can i do it ?

thanks

Comment: As a sidenote: language can not be learned in _xy_ days little less in _xy_ minutes.

Comment: "usually in c++ i can write this code:" ... but c++/cli is not c++. you need to invest more than 5 minutes :P

Comment: i know that. i want to show you what i mean, because all day i am search for a answer this article is the most useful source that i found

Comment: How did you create the project. It doesn't seam that you enabled the compiler option /CLR. Please read the documentation, a book, or a tutorial.

Comment: BTW: wstring is OK, for unicode too ;)

Comment: You should use unicode literals: `L"Blue"`. Note `L` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

> i get a lot of errors!

Please don't make us guess what errors you're getting.

I was able to compile your code without any problems. Since you didn't say what errors you're getting, the only thing I can think of is that you're missing `using namespace System;`, which will end up giving you `error C2065: 'String' : undeclared identifier`, and a bunch of syntax errors.

You can either add `using namespace System;`, or explicitly specify the namespace `System::String` everywhere.